# Stuck flap inside gas filler pipe preventing nozzle insertion

Tags: mercedes-benz

I just bought a Mercedes-Benz C 180 kompressor, year 2004. I tried to refuel it, but there's a stuck metal flap making it impossible to insert the filler nozzle. I'm sure that the nozzle should fit, because there's typically only three options, gasoline octan numbers 95 and 98 and diesel. I tried both the gasoline nozzles to be sure.

The flap is most likely the one that should core the hole but doesn't and it looks like it's bent. There's also a spring like metal piece behind the flap. I tried to poke it with a screw driver, but couldn't get it to move.

Is this thing broken or just stuck? Can I somehow remove the whole flap?

Here's the picture of what can be seen.

[image]

Comment: it's weird to see it, I never know the fuel hole have a flap in it...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure you are trying to use the correct type of fuel? Fuel filler nozzles are usually sized to prevent you from putting the wrong type of fuel into specific vehicles. Just a thought.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 in the UK, petrol (gasoline) nozzles are smaller diameter than diesel.

Comment: @alephzero - Kinda my point :o)

Comment: My car has a similar flapper. It sometimes goes cock-eyed and grabs my siphon hose. The actual hole size is what prevents the wrong nozzle being used. I'm not sure what is the function of this flapper, maybe to stop splashes against the filler cap while driving? Maybe it can be bent out of the way if it is not critical.